# html Multilingual website - Language latency occurring

Tags: javascript, html

I'm implementing a multilingual solution on my website : I detect the browser language of the user.

What I have in the HTML is the default text in English.

All the text objects are being assigned an id.

Then in a JS sheet I use innerHTML to replace the text in the correct language, to translate into French.

---

HTML

```
<div>
<h3 id="test">
This is a Test !
</h3>
</div>
```

JS

```
function adjust_languages() {

    // change all object text, if french
    if (sprache == "french") {

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Ceci est un test !";

    }
```

This works quite well. However, when the user's connection is not very fast, a latency occurs between the moment when the HTML text is displayed in English and the moment when it gets translated into French.

In other words, the user sees English for let's say 1 second, before it gets translated into French.

I was thinking of getting rid completely of text in the HTML and have the English language in the JS as well, but that would mean 0 text in the HTML file, which I think is not very usual...

What would be your advice to have the right language displayed at first, without any latency occurring ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd translate on the server. Alternatively If the text is not huge, you can have both and hide one with css

Comment: Can't you translate your pages server side? Is it a static site in plain html? Are server side languages out of question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make a text box on what language you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Langtest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <input type="text" id="lang" placeholder="Type a language">
       <button onclick="adjust_languages()">Change!</button>
       <h3 id="test">This is a test!</h3>
    </body>
    <script>
       var sprache = document.getElementById("lang").textContent;
       function adjust_languages()
       {
           if (sprache = "french")
           {
               document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Ceci est un test !";
           }
       }
    </script>
</html>
```

Think you must need a var so no lag will happen even you have slow connection and do not use external APIs

Answer (score 0):

Either translate on the server or use a client template library to translate on the client. I'd recommend mustache because it's very simple to use and lightweight. It'll make your life easier and it might run faster than your own solution.

Also if you don't want to do that anyway: use textContent instead of innerHTML. The latter needs to determine if the content is HTML or not and evaluate any element it finds while textContent just creates a text node with the string in it.